# Java Layout - Leaving a certain space for a non-visible element

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I'm making a swing application for myself and have been trying out a few different layouts. One thing that I'm having an issue with in all the layouts I've tried (BoxLayout, FlowLayout, BorderLayout, GroupLayout) is that I want to hide one of my elements, but I want to leave a blank space of the exact size in it's place. At the moment, when the element disappears, or if I set the element as not visible on startup, then either the whole window is smaller, or something will happen like a textfield will expand to a rediculous size.

Specifying the sizes of the elements seem to have no effect at all.

Is there a way I can have an invisible element that still takes up it's space in the layout?

Why are my elements not being given the sizes that I specify?

Grateful for any pointers.

Many thanks

Comment: _Specifying the sizes of the elements seem to have no effect at all_ that's expected behaviour: it's the core task of a LayoutManager to locate and size the components as it deems correct, manual interence is simply ignored :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [`Box.createRigidArea`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.html#createRigidArea%28java.awt.Dimension%29).  The description is simple enough:

> Creates an invisible component that's always the specified size.

This creates a `Component` that can be used in any layout.

Answer (score 1):

The only completely safe way of "want to hide one of my elements, but I want to leave a blank space of the exact size in it's place" is a LayoutManager that includes invisible components in its layout process. If none of the core implementations does it, use a third-party manager like f.i. MigLayout.

Note: Box.RigidArea has a fixed size - so its good enough for a placeholder at a specific layout state, but needs to be manually adjusted if f.i. parent size changes.

Comment: Great. Thanks for your answer. I'll have a look at the MigLayout.

Comment: @kelopatra DesignGridLayout does it also ;-)

Comment: @jfpoilpret hach, how could I forget that :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try placing `component.setVisible(false);` after `frame.pack();`

Comment: thanks. I already tried this. Placing the component before pack() meant that the window was smaller. Placing after meant that one of the other components expanded to fill the gap. This was using BoxLayout.